# Redirect gateway traffic linux

Tags: linux, networking

lets say you have multiple server boxes with vm's

10.0.0.0/24 => gateway 10.0.0.1
10.0.1.0/24 => gateway 10.0.1.1
10.0.2.0/24 => gateway 10.0.2.1

and now move the vm's to dev server box

10.0.0.0/16 => gateway 10.0.0.1

now the gateways 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.2.1 are not working anymore.

how to redirect the 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.2.1 traffic to 10.0.0.1?

this

ip route add 10.0.2.1 via 10.0.0.1 dev vmbr0

and that

-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.2.1/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1

is not working...

Answer (score 0):

well if you imagine that nobody knows the answer.. or at least don't want to share it without bitcoin transfer!

https://ostechnix.com/how-to-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-single-network-card-in-linux/